# Do I need to use an outdoor or wet electrical box for garage sink area?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I'm installing some metal surface-mounted boxes for receptacles in my garage utility sink area, with emt between them.

I will use a GFCI receptacle, but do I need to use water-tight conduit and boxes because this will be surface mount near a garage utility sink?

I'm in California.

Comment: Try to avoid using multiple GFCI receptacles on the same circuit.  GFCIs have the ability to protect downline loads: that is the only purpose of the LOAD terminals.  If you do that, you also protect the wires between GFCI and downline loads.  Just right for a sink area.

Comment: I understand that, but I was more wondering about the surface mount boxes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If the outlet is not being splashed you can use a standard box with knockouts, also a standard outlet. This would be Similar to a kitchen or bar. If the outlet is within 6' of the sink it will need to be a GFCI or GFCI protected within 6' of the sink. Indoors water tight fittings are not needed. For example is the area finished with sheetrock? If the sheet rock is ok it is not a damp /wet area as it will fall apart quickly being in a damp / wet area. FWIW All garage outlets need to be GFCI protected by current code.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer since we don't really know where these receptacles are in relation to the sink. It really depends on how the area is going to be classified. Is it a damp location or a wet (usually interpreted as raintight) location.

By definition in NEC Article 100 a raintight requirement is for construction that prevents water from entering the device encloser due to beating rain or in your case splashing or dripping of water. That would require N-3r enclosures and water tight conduit fittings.

A damp location is an area where moister is present in an exposed area due to condensation, humidity or other indirect moisture. Most standard boxes and conduit fitting are allowed in this type of area. I would sill use a N-3r box.

In any case you need to use receptacles which are marked with the WR (water resistant) designation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would liken it to a regular kitchen if, for some reason, I had to use emt and surface boxes.